# ssh master - execute su remotely

Tags: ssh, sudo, su

I have a server `S` that I need to connect to.

I'm connecting to `S` as user `asdf` with control master and after that I perform some stuff:

```
ssh -N -f -M -o ControlPath=$SSHSOCKET ${USER}@${IP} -p ${PORT} -i id_rsa
ssh -to ControlPath=$SSHSOCKET ${USER}@${IP} -p ${PORT} "su -c whoami && hostname && exit"
```

It works as expected, but second line asks me  for password.

I am trying such fix:

```
echo 'qwerty' | ssh -t -to ControlPath=$SSHSOCKET ${K3_USER}@${IP} -p ${PORT} "su -c whoami && hostname && exit"
```

but it gets even worse:

```
muxserver_accept_control: tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Password:
```

For me, it's mandatory to ssh as `asdf` first. I also can't make any other ssh control master connections. I also can't modify any config on the target machine.

I just need to switch to root via ssh somehow. Any ideas ?

Comment: cant you move the password into the remote command: `ssh ... "echo 'qwerty' | su -c ..."`

Comment: @meuh Then I got: `su: must be run from a terminal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, interactive password problems are solved by using the `expect` command which creates
an intermediary pseudo-tty to talk to the process. Here's an alternative python version using the
equivalent python-pexpect package. Create a python file run.py:

```
import sys,pexpect
(pw,cmd) = sys.argv[1:]
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
child.expect(r'(?i)Password:')
child.sendline(pw)
print child.read()
```

and run it with the password and command to run as parameters:

```
python run.py  'qwerty' 'ssh -t -o ControlPath=$SSHSOCKET ${K3_USER}@${IP} -p ${PORT} "su -c whoami && hostname"'
```